# How to create inline if without else case

Tags: dart, flutter

Does *Dart* support a syntax to have an inline if without an else case? I sometimes find myself in a situation to create a flutter layout where this might be really helpful

```
new Row(children: <Widget>[
    new Text(item.name),
    item.name2 != null ? new Text(item.name2) : new Container(),
]
```

In this example the empty container is unnecessary so I was hoping for something like this:

```
new Row(children: <Widget>[
    new Text(item.name),
    item.name2 != null ? new Text(item.name2),
]
```

Comment: You may want to read https://medium.com/flutter-community/quick-tip-sync-a-taste-of-the-future-9be4cd6993f4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there is no inline if without else
but in your case you're using if only to check only if it's null or not

dart have :

```
x = someVar ?? 0
```

here dart checks if someVar == null ? if true sets x value to 0, if false sets it to someVar value

but flutter will never let you add null to it's widget tree, so your can't use it in row/col

Answer (score 13):

You can do this:

```
myVar == null ? 0 : myVar
```

If `myVar` is `null` then is `0`, else then `myVar`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to call a function you can use like this:

```
String s; //null

s == null ? print("if shorthand working") : {};
```

For variable assignment:

```
String c = "not null value";
String b; //null

var a = b ?? c;
```

Now a = c.

> Visual Studio Code tip: add this to ignore linting for a line
> // ignore: unnecessary_statements

Answer (score 2):

In general, the "inline if" can be written in darts as follows:

```
<condition> ? <expression 1> : <expression 2>
```

So that if `<condition>` evaluates to `True`, then `<expression 1>` is returned and otherwise `<expression 2>`.

For example:

```
result = myVar == null ? 0 : myVar ;

// if myVar is null -> result = 0
// if myVar is not null -> result = myVar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually plans to include a similar feature into the Dart language itself.

For a preview of how it would look like, take a look at this article by Remi

https://medium.com/flutter-community/quick-tip-sync-a-taste-of-the-future-9be4cd6993f4

And some accompanying Github issues

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17862

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/47

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/78